# How to make property in Vue component to be reactive

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to create a new component:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
    props: {
        displayed: {
            type: Boolean
        }
    },
    template: `
        <div v-bind:class="{'modal': true, 'auth-required': true, 'show-modal': displayed }">
            <div class="modal__content">
                <img src="/img/popup/close.svg" v-on:click="displayed = false;" alt="close" class="modal__closeBtn modal__closeBtn-questions" />
                <slot></slot>
                <img src="/img/popup/dog.png" alt="dog" class="modal__contentImg" />
            </div>
        </div>`,
    data: function () {
        return {
            isDisplayed: this.displayed
        };
    },
})
```

But when i'm trying to bind displayed property to another property from the page it doesn't work when `modal.authRequired` value changes:

```
<mycomponent :displayed="modal.authRequired"></mycomponent>
```

How to make `isDisplayed` to be reactive when `modal.authRequired` changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a watch to your prop:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
    props: {
        displayed: {
            type: Boolean
        }
    },
    template: `
        <div v-bind:class="{'modal': true, 'auth-required': true, 'show-modal': isDisplayed }">
            <div class="modal__content">
                <img src="/img/popup/close.svg" v-on:click="displayed = false;" alt="close" class="modal__closeBtn modal__closeBtn-questions" />
                <slot></slot>
                <img src="/img/popup/dog.png" alt="dog" class="modal__contentImg" />
            </div>
        </div>`,
    data: function () {
        return {
            isDisplayed: this.displayed
        };
    },
    watch: {
        displayed(newValue) {
            // Update the data value
            this.isDisplayed = newValue;
        }
    }
})
```

Also, notice that I changed the 'show-modal' binding: `'show-modal': isDisplayed`

Answer (score 0):

Reactive properties are the computed one :https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: But i need to initialize computed property, is that possible?